# QGIS modeler not finding GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-modeler

I have problem to create simply process in QGIS modeler.
I got error message:

> Algorithm is not available

Why its not available, same GRASS algorithm works in QGIS desktop?

What is that red box in left side?

[image: GRASS r.watershed algoritm]

Comment: Maybe you ran QGIS without GRASS. -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tSsn.png

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS 3.22 GRASS and SAGA integration system changed within QGIS.

You have to activate the SAGA and GRASS providers in the plugins menubar to keep using their tools.

[image]