# Both GRASS and SAGA fails on QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga

After having trouble with GRASS and SAGA on my Windows laptop, I have just reinstalled QGIS but it has not solved anything. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot for the world figure it out.

I've tried it on a simple DEM file, but I get several issue codes. I've added log files of two examples here: [Log files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r20gtnhfv6qaaed/AADfd6gZVePBcMk3RfI4mEHIa?dl=0)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The Saga command says:

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.

 - C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_WQFIIg/dce5b27efedc456ea305460223f6bdfa/LENGTH.sdat
```

Grass says:

```
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
```

and further down in the log files:

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.
 - C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_WQFIIg/485ddd15320343aeb5d63243e34dc371/flowlength.tif
 - C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_WQFIIg/4d4c7ba1270c414492063e08a979c385/flowline.gpkg
 - C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_WQFIIg/7dcae902f4254baa8b2537900da9b24f/flowaccumulation.tif
```

I tried using the Grass Tools component, but I get this error message for any tool I try to use:

```
Cannot start module C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/bin/v.in.ogr.exe

PATH=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/bin;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/scripts;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./grass/scripts;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./grass/modules;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem

PATH=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/bin;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/scripts;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./grass/scripts;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./grass/modules;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem

PYTHONPATH=;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/etc/python;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/gui/wxpython

command: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/bin/v.in.ogr.exe --interface-description
```

I tried the actual Grass application, but get this message on startup

```
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...

          __________  ___   __________    _______________
         / ____/ __ \/   | / ___/ ___/   / ____/  _/ ___/
        / / __/ /_/ / /| | \__ \\_  \   / / __ / / \__ \
       / /_/ / _, _/ ___ |___/ /__/ /  / /_/ // / ___/ /
       \____/_/ |_/_/  |_/____/____/   \____/___//____/

Welcome to GRASS GIS 7.8.7
GRASS GIS homepage:                      https://grass.osgeo.org
This version running through:            Command Prompt (C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe)
Help is available with the command:      g.manual -i
See the licence terms with:              g.version -c
See citation options with:               g.version -x
If required, restart the GUI with:       g.gui wxpython
When ready to quit enter:                exit

Launching <wxpython> GUI in the background, please wait...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.1219]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Med ensamrätt.

C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 3427, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\wxgui.py", line 83, in show_main_gui
    mainframe = GMFrame(parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, workspace=self.workspaceFile)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\lmgr\frame.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.notebook = self._createNoteBook()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\lmgr\frame.py", line 326, in _createNoteBook
    self.goutput = GConsoleWindow(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gui_core\goutput.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.cmdPrompt = GPromptSTC(parent=self, menuModel=self._menuModel)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gui_core\prompt.py", line 138, in __init__
    GPrompt.__init__(self, parent=parent, menuModel=menuModel)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gui_core\prompt.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.mapList = self._getListOfMaps()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gui_core\prompt.py", line 100, in _getListOfMaps
    result['raster'] = grass.list_strings('raster')
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 1282, in list_strings
    for line in read_command("g.list",
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 503, in read_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, stdout, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 342, in handle_errors
    raise CalledModuleError(module=None, code=code,
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None g.list --q -m type=raster ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 3221225785. See errors in the (error) output.
```

Computer info:

```
Dell Precision 5560
11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11950H @ 2.60GHz   2.61 GHz
Windows 10 Pro
QGIS version: 3.28.0-Firenze
QGIS code revision: ed3ad0430f3
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.5.2
GEOS version: 3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.0, September 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: 434757)
GRASS version: 7.8.7
SAGA version 7.8.2 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
```

Comment: You should add note details to get an answer

Comment: Did you try this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443265/162856 ?

Comment: @wanderzen Yes, I've checked both plugins.

Comment: The GRASS GIS Warning "WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows" you can happily ignore.

Comment: You tried the actual GRASS GIS application, but got this message on startup: "... wxpython..." is not related to QGIS. For that purpose, please either install the full standalone installer or OSGeo4W, see https://grass.osgeo.org/download/windows/

Comment: Overall, I'd suggest to separate the GRASS GIS and the SAGA related double-question into two single questions as they are distinct software packages.